# Intercept the SSO cookie before the authorization server redirects the page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config, openid-connect

I have been banging my head for over a week to intercept the SSO cookie before the Authorization server redirects me my app page. 
I'm implementing [mitreid-connect](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki/Client-configuration) for openid configuration. I have followed the documentation in the link and configured it using Java Config. Everything works fine, the redirects and etc., but I'm trying to implement `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` to intercept the SSO cookie before the authorization server consumes it and generates the IdToken.

Please let me know if this is not right. I'm very new to spring-security and its scraping my scales off and its driving me crazy how to get hold to sso cookie

I have found this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/49796-need-to-allow-auto-login)

Please help me

```
@Configuration
public class filter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    @Bean(name = "singleSignOnFilter")
    public String filter() {
        return "PRE_AUTH_FILTER";
    }
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
        for(int i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cookie[i].getName() + " - " +  cookie[i].getValue());
        }
        return null;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Inject
    private ClientDetailsEntity client;

    @Inject
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    public ProviderManager providerManager() {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProvider = new LinkedList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        authenticationProvider.add(oidcAuthProvider());

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider oidcAuthProvider() {
        return new OIDCAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean(name = "authoritiesMapper")
    public OIDCAuthoritiesMapper authorityMapper() {
        NamedAdminAuthoritiesMapper namedAdminAuthMapper = new NamedAdminAuthoritiesMapper();
        namedAdminAuthMapper.setAdmins(admins());
        return namedAdminAuthMapper;
    }

    @Bean(name = "admins")
    public Set<SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority> admins() {
        Set<SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority> admin = new HashSet<SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority>();

        return admin;
    }

    @Bean(name = "openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter")
    public Filter openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter() {
        OIDCAuthenticationFilter oidcAuthFilter = new OIDCAuthenticationFilter();
        oidcAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(providerManager());
        oidcAuthFilter.setIssuerService(issuerService());
        oidcAuthFilter.setClientConfigurationService(clientConfigurationService());
        oidcAuthFilter.setAuthRequestUrlBuilder(authRequestUrlBuilder());

        return oidcAuthFilter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "issuerService")
    public IssuerService issuerService() {
        StaticSingleIssuerService issuerService = new StaticSingleIssuerService();
        issuerService.setIssuer(issuer);

        return issuerService;
    }

    @Bean(name = "clientConfigurationService")
    public ClientConfigurationService clientConfigurationService() {
        StaticClientConfigurationService clientConfigService = new StaticClientConfigurationService();
        clientConfigService.setClients(registeredClient());

        return clientConfigService;
    }

    @Bean(name = "clients")
    public Map<String, RegisteredClient> registeredClient() {
        Map<String, RegisteredClient> oidcRegClients = new HashMap<String, RegisteredClient>();
        oidcRegClients.put(issuer, new RegisteredClient(client));
        return oidcRegClients;
    }

    @Bean(name = "authRequestUrlBuilder")
    public AuthRequestUrlBuilder authRequestUrlBuilder() {
        return new PlainAuthRequestUrlBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/openid_connect_login")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/items")
                            .authenticated()
                        .anyRequest()
                            .permitAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the sso cookie? The cookie for the authorization server session?

Comment: so when i hit my app url, the authorization server takes me to authentication page, like google login page. Here I give my credentials and signin, so i get assigned with sso cookie. After here I get a page to allow access. Once i click on allow, the page gets redirected to my app and now my cookie is not here. Can i intercept the cookie before it disappears

Answer (score 0):

You are on right path. I think, your question is how to extract the information(for e.g. username) from cookie and then use this information to authorize the user. Here are the steps, to clear some air.

1. Configure a subclass of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` (e.g. below )

   ```
   public class CustomPreAuthenticatedFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
   protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
       // below sample extracts the username from header.You can pull from cookie
       String expectedHeaderNameContainingUsername = "abcd";
       String username = request.getHeader(expectedHeaderNameContainingUsername);
       return username;
   }


   protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
       String expectedHeaderNameContainingCredentials = "";
       if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(expectedHeaderNameContainingCredentials)) {
           return request.getHeader(expectedHeaderNameContainingCredentials);
       }
       return "N/A";
   }
   ```

   }
2. Simply register the above filter with HTTP security with 
     http.addFilter(Filter filter);

It seems your filter is not registered with spring security.

3. The `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` forwards the result of getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(..) to authmanager to build the principal object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I add the filter like this ? `http.addFilterBefore(openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class).addFilter(CustomPreAuthenticatedFilter)
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/openid_connect_login")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                .and()....`

Comment: http.addFilter(CustomPreAuthenticated‌​Filter).addFilterBefore(openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter  .class) .formLogin() .loginPage("/openid_connect_login") .and() .logout() .and() ....

Comment: `Configure` method in my configuration class is called when the server is started, I had put break point at `OIDCAuthenticationFilter` to check when it is loading. If I add the filter, will to be loaded before I hit the url or will it work after I hit the url ?